# GitHub CLI automatic login within devcontainer

Tags: github, vscode-devcontainer, github-cli, devcontainer

Every time I create a devcontainer in vscode, I have to login again using the GitHub CLI. Is there a way to automate this? Have GitHub CLI login automatically on the container (exploiting the fact that I am logged in already in the host machine)?